# How do i get current user's RegionalSettings using .net \ rest request?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, rest, .net

I'm trying to get current user's regional settings.

`var regionalSettings = context.Web.RegionalSettings` works but there is no `RegionalSettings` on `context.Web.CurrentUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing-

I need the timezone to handle the dates of an upload file just after the upload. Since requesting current user's and web's `TimeZone` objects got pretty messy and took too much time I decided to conclude the time zone from file's modified property:

```
var fileModifiedDate = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields.Modified; 
return Math.round(moment.utc(fileModifiedDate).diff(moment.utc(), 'hours', true));
```